# Android AlertDialog Builder with Edittext setView shows at bottom?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi I am using AlertDialog with no custom views, setting array adapter of lists by using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
builder.setView(input);
builder.setTitle("Please Select");

String[] listStrings = {"string1", "string2"};
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, listStrings);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(arrayAdapter, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

builder.show();
```

and I want to attach `EditText` for searching list, But `EditText` shows at the end of list. I want `EditText` top of list, so please suggest me without using custom layouts.

```
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
builder.setView(input);
```

I tried by changing sequence of `builder.setView(input);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
  layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(input);
    builder.setTitle("Please Select");

    String[] listStrings = {"string1", "string2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, listStrings);

    ListView list=new ListView(this);


    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    layout.addView(list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
   builder.setView(layout);
    builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
boolean checked = false;


AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parm = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linear.setLayoutParams(parm);
        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Please Select");
        linear.addView(input);

        String[] listStrings = {"string1", "string2"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, listStrings);
        ListView list=new ListView(this);


        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        linear.addView(list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                CheckedTextView chk = (CheckedTextView) view;
                Log.d("", "Checked = " + checked);
                checked = checked ? false:true;
                chk.setChecked(checked);

            }
        });
        builder.setView(linear);

        builder.show();
```